# Not getting "next_page_token" back with nearbySearch or textSearch using javascript places library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, google-places

I am trying to capture all of the restaurants in a specific city by iterating over the results google returns using nearbySearch or textSearch. So far I can only get the first 20 results. I was expecting to see a parameter in the response called "next_page_token" that I can send with my next request to get the next set of results, however, no matter which API I hit or the size of the radius, I never get back the "next_page_token" in my response from google.

I have tried specifically requesting the "pagetoken" as a callback parameter in my callback function, and to my surprise it does provide me with the pagetoken details. I tried mapping the pagetoken.l to the pagetoken in my consecutive request but it still returns the same set of results.

I have been searching online for hours and can't a solution to this problem.

Using Node and VueJS to make the client side request. The example code below is inside one of the VueJS templates in the script section. The textSearch is almost identical except I replace the location & radius with a query that uses keywords to perform the search.

**Example using nearbySearch**

```
initialize(addressData, placeResults) {
    console.log("Address Data", addressData)
    console.log("Place Results", placeResults)

    this.location = {
        lat: addressData.latitude,
        lng: addressData.longitude
    }

    this.initMap()

},
initMap() {
    console.log("Refs", this.$refs)
    console.log("location", this.location)

    let map = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, {
        center: this.location,
        zoom: 12,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false
    })

    let request = {
        location: this.location,
        radius: 10000,
        type: ['restaurant']      
    }

    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
    service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status, pagetoken) => {
        console.log("Results", results)
        console.log("Status", status)
        console.log("Pagetoken", pagetoken)
        if (pagetoken.hasNextPage) {
            this.hasNextPage = true
            this.pagetoken = pagetoken.l
        }
    })
}
```

I won't post the results since the JSON is very long, but the results only contain an array of restaurants found and nothing else.

**Pagetoken response from callback**

```
{
  "l": "CqQCHwEAAHGTZMjzfdC-1RcLP8jYBOGy7oUFztGWLSWOCQGAcHe4NgVLfJRl1Yl1GH0G-mju4-A-1fwtDChtmoSQn_qNBIkiK8co2KWy28M3BhV95yvLAswbfTIRwB9wZAev2aaRc3Yd2_nY9dWbFMhv-KppnTGKJj7dYndtj-yyUwV2evznSAE_t5Fcd7OYHmBXPHjSL54jfadw2B96wEx_Ju-5O30J14LlXLkJQZHhCNaD-kb-OAofXVeY5My1-LavHDgdkw49vTeiMou7jU4wB7m47ZSWAB2NChYt5tHLeHPA8n7aCRc40cEzNwpI8T3nwrw8tsuBx9Lbh8mToaUbULBSTzKQzr3DC6v2N4AGDuK4v6A_AdzKZVfhD_GNcM1olyQ2xRIQ0sAvkEOTSJ4ByvjcRXs_uhoUm0CPRm7lHLG593au02QlXTEjeg4",
  "j": 1528657652795,
  "hasNextPage": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation the third parameter in the callback function of the nearby search is the object of type `PlaceSearchPagination`:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/places-service#PlaceSearchPagination

The `PlaceSearchPagination` exposes public property `hasNextPage` of boolean type and public method `nextPage()` to get next page of results.

> **nextPage()** - Fetches the next page of results. Uses the same callback function that was provided to the first search request.

I believe you should use the following code to get next page of results when available

```
let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status, pagetoken) => {
    console.log("Results", results)
    console.log("Status", status)
    console.log("Pagetoken", pagetoken)
    if (pagetoken.hasNextPage) {
        pagetoken.nextPage();
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked as you described. I didn't realize there was a nextPage() method in the callback. For anyone reading this, when you call pagetoken.nextPage(), it automatically runs the code from your nearbySearch again automatically a couple seconds later, and a third final time if there are more results after that.

Comment: Depending on implementation this will show 20 markers on map and after approx. 2 seconds callback will be executed again and add another 20 to the map and if there's more result it will fetch 20 more after 2 sec. (2 sec delay forced by google maps api). All results can be displayed at once but only after all results are fetched so after 4-6 seconds.

`if (pagetoken.hasNextPage) {
        pagetoken.nextPage();
} else {
        showAllMarkers();
}`

Comment: If you pass `pagetoken` externally (so that you can present paging options in UI), how do you re-use it when calling `nearbySearch` again? Or put another way, how to go to the next page _outside_ of this function?